# WHERE over a varchar field with multiple Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, varchar

I need make a query on SQL Server 2005 to match this scenario, I have a `varchar(max)` field with some id's like: "`12323,12345,123,434345,2324,1211212`" and the user will give me a group, the first 3 numbers; So, in where clause I'll have to match each of this id separate by a comma, any suggestion? How can I do this?

```
product | id
prod01    1212,211,3434342,54532
prod02    323,323,424,5435,35345
prod03    2323,1212

@UserEntry='123'
```

Comment: Fix your data structure.  You should not be storing lists of things in strings.  Use a junction table -- the correct database approach.

Comment: My suggestion is to fix your database. That kind of structure should never be used.

Comment: I can't do that,the database is not my,the data was  purchase this way by  a third part =/

Comment: Even if you were given the data in that structure, you can create a new table(s) with the correct structure, and copy the data into it. Or create your own new database if you have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a function to split the strings into separate values. Here's one. I don't know who wrote it originally, but it's been in our library since forever:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.split_string (@v_string VARCHAR(2000), @v_delimiter VARCHAR(1))
    RETURNS @output TABLE (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, item VARCHAR(2000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @v_item VARCHAR(2000);
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@v_delimiter, @v_string, 0) <> 0
    BEGIN
       SET @v_item   = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v_string, 1, CHARINDEX(@v_delimiter, @v_string, 0) - 1)));
       SET @v_string = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@v_string, CHARINDEX(@v_delimiter, @v_string, 0) + LEN(@v_delimiter), LEN(@v_string))));
       IF LEN(@v_item) > 0
       BEGIN
           INSERT INTO @output SELECT @v_item;
       END;
    END;

    IF LEN(@v_string) > 0         -- catch the last item
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @output SELECT @v_string;
    END;

    RETURN
END
```

This will return the separate values as a table variable, from which you can use `IF @UserEntry IN ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should change the data structure to have a junction table.  This is a table with one row per `product` and `id`.  Storing lists in strings is really, really bad.  Storing integers in strings adds insult to injury.

But, sometimes you are stuck with someone else's bad decisions.  If so, you can use `like`:

```
where ',' + id + ',' like '%,' @UserEntry + ',%'
```

However, this is a last resort and such queries cannot make use of an index.  Fixing the data structure is the best option, by far.

Comment: Sometimes you are stuck with someone else's bad decisions,this is exactly the case :(